# May a French citizen obtain a visa for Vietnam while in the country during the visa "free" 15 days?

Tags: visas, vietnam, french-citizens

As a French citizen I can enter Vietnam without a visa for a stay that doesn't exceed 15 days.

Is it possible during those 15 days to get a visa while already in the country?

Answer (score 6):

Seems "Yes":

> 2. Renewal Vietnam visa: means that you are granted a new visa stamp and visa sticker on your passport with the new duration permission. The staying length is valid maximum in 3 months. Moreover the visa renewal fee is higher than the visa extension fee because we have to pay stamping fee and visa sticker fee for you. Visa renewal is ready for someone who:
>
>    - Entered Vietnam with visa exemption.

[From](https://www.vietnam-evisa.org/services/view/vietnam-visa-extension-and-renewal.html).