# Can an electronic visa for Vietnam be extended?

Tags: visas, vietnam, e-visas, romanian-citizens

This year, getting an e-visa for Vietnam was introduced for my country, Romania.
However, it is only for 30 days (touristic purpose), yet I want to stay longer.

Is it possible to extend an e-visa while in Vietnam?

If yes, what is the procedure, papers involved, costs and possibilities?

Comment: Related, though it may not answer the question directly:  [May a French citizen obtain a visa for Vietnam while in the country during the visa “free” 15 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86020/may-a-french-citizen-obtain-a-visa-for-vietnam-while-in-the-country-during-the-v)

Comment: Did you get your e-visa through [Vietnam-evisa.org](https://www.vietnam-evisa.org/about-us.html)? If so, here's the [page that tells you how to do it](https://www.vietnam-evisa.org/services/view/vietnam-visa-extension-and-renewal.html)

Comment: @Dorothy that one is private organisation's website. And I think it helps you prearrange your Visa on Arrival only. The offical eVisa of Vietnam is https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn

Comment: @Danh yes, just trying to see through which OP obtained his; ty.

Answer (score 2):

A pilot e-visa program launched in 2017 allows visitors from 40 eligible countries to apply for visas online through the [Vietnam Immigration Department](https://www.immigration.gov.vn/). E-visas are single-entry, valid for 30 days, and cost US $25. While you apply online, and can print visa, you still have to present it for validation when you enter Vietnam, actually serving as a Visa on Arrival.

Once in the country, one option is to request an extension at the Vietnam Immigration Office; the Hanoi location is 44 Trần Phú, Điện Biên. Another is at 161 Nguyen Du Street, Ho Chi Minh City.

Vietnam does authorize visa agencies, and you may wish to use such services to extend your stay. A quick search (no affiliation) returns [Vietnam-eVisa](https://www.vietnam-evisa.org/services/view/vietnam-visa-extension-and-renewal.html), [Vietnam Immigration](http://www.vietnam-immigration.net/services/view/vietnam-visa-extension-and-renewal.html), and [Vietnam Visa Easy](http://www.vietnamvisa-easy.com/vietnam-visa-extension) as some options.

As with most in-country visa extension processes, it should be done prior the expiration of your current visa, and should be requested, at a minimum, 4-7 days in advance.

Comment: About e-visa is not mentioned explicitly it can be extended. Are you sure the information mentioned above is valid for e-visa also?